# order by in sql after subtracting column values

Tags: sql, mysql

i've a sql table with 3 columns: **id**, **start**, **end**

i've to select all(SELECT *) the results and arrange them descending from the (**start-end**) value..

can i do that in a single sql command?
any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.start,
       t.end,
       t.start - t.end AS difference
  FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY difference DESC
```